# Put "tag" in the right side of the text input in Formkit (vue) (the one with the tag is the concept)

Tags: vue.js, formkit

[concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihibL.png)[actual form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVbAx.png)

This is the code from my FormKit (vue), I didn't write this but I have to work with this now and I'm a bit lost because I never used FormKit

```
<FormKit
              type="form"
              ref="formRef"
              @input="onFormInit"
              :actions="false"
              :incomplete-message="false"
              :config="{ validationVisibility: 'submit' }"
              @submit="return"
            >
              <div class="row">
                <FormKit
                  v-for="answer in (waterGI?.Q_PROD_PLANT_WATER_GI_001.answers as string[])"
                  type="text"
                  @keypress="preventForbiddenChars($event, /[^\d,.]/gm)"
                  :name="`Q_PROD_PLANT_WATER_DI_001_${
                    availableWaterSources.find(
                      (source) => source.id.toString() === answer
                    )?.id
                  }`"
                  v-model="
                    prodPlantResourceDataInputForm[
                      `Q_PROD_PLANT_WATER_DI_001_${
                        availableWaterSources.find(
                          (source) => source.id.toString() === answer
                        )?.id
                      }`
                    ].answers
                  "
                  :label="`${$t(
                    'carbonFootprint.facility.water.questions.prodPlant.DI.Q1'
                  )} (${
                    availableWaterSources.find(
                      (source) => source.id.toString() === answer
                    )?.name
                  })`"
                  :placeholder="$t('form.genericInputPlaceholder')"
                />
              </div>
            </FormKit>
          </FormKit>
```

I don't even know how to begin working on this to make that tag-like thing